# this losing scope not see how i could use apply/call

Tags: scope, this

```
var DBProcessor = function(name){this.name=name;};
DBProcessor.prototype.CallBack = function(err, d){
if (err) {
    console.log("writeHosts. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
} else {
    console.log(".........");        
    console.log(this.name);  // >>>> UNDEFINED
    console.log(".........");
}
}
var DBP = new DBProcessor("Hosts");
function writeHosts(){
...
..         
db.batchWriteItem(param, DBP.CallBack);}
```

how can i get a variable inside DBP "this" is losing scope and i have no influence how DBP.CallBack is called

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var db = new doc.DynamoDB();
```

so i am not see how i could use apply() or call()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no influence over how it's called, you can't have it as a prototype function. Either `bind` it in the constructor, or define it as a closure within the constructor and use the old `var _this = this;` trick to keep a reference to the correct `this`.

Comment: not sure what you mean
this seams to work


function DBProcessor(_this){
    return {
        CallBack: function(err, d){
            if (err) {
                console.log("writeHosts. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log(".........");
                console.log(_this.a); 
                console.log(".........");
            }
        }
    };
}

var DBP = {a:1};
DBP.p = new DBProcessor(DBP);

Comment: @Ino: That's a very bizarre way of doing it. What part of my answer didn't you understand? Did you read the documentation for `bind`? Do you know what a closure is? If not, better get googling.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm
currently i have this and it works 
if anything speaks against this let me now will google "bind" in the mean time

```
function DBProcessor(_this){
_this = this;
this.b = 1;
this.CallBack = function(err, d){
    if (err) {
        console.log("writeHosts. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log(_this.a);
        console.log(_this.b); 
        console.log(".........");
    }
};
return this;}
var DBP = new DBProcessor();
DBP.a = 2;
```

here with bind

```
function DBProcessor(){
return {
    a:1,
    _CallBack: function (err, d){
        if (err) {
            console.log("writeHosts. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log(this.a);
            console.log(this.b);
            console.log(".........");
        }
    }
};
}

var DBP = new DBProcessor();
DBP.b = 2;
DBP.CallBack = DBP._CallBack.bind(DBP);
```